# In-App purchase for different login user in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Am creating cloud storage app with multiple user access(like Google Drive app).

I want to add expand storage feature using in-App purchase(1 year validity after that user need to renew).If it is single user i can go with Auto-renewing subscriptions.But i need to provide this feature to each login user.

1. Can i go with Non-renewing subscriptions
2. If i use Non-renewing subscriptions,i need to manage subscription date and end date in my DB

If u have any idea please share with me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offering a year of service as a consumable IAP might be a valid solution to your problem, since you want to associate the purchase not with the iTunes user, but the user of your service. The issue with subscriptions is that they need to be restorable across all devices for the iTunes user, which is not what you want -- you don't want someone to auth with your system with a different account and restore subscription. Rather, you want to associate a user authenticated on your system with your content, which you could do through a consumable.

You've probably already looked at it, but Apple's IAP documentation [can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.I already go through the IAP document.I think i can go with consumable type and validity i can mange in my server.